# Insert temporary DOM element for onClick hander

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom, reactjs

I've an HTML table generated by React render() which is tied to a websocket for realtime updates.

What I'm looking to do is attach a React event handler "onClick" to the cell which replaces the value in the cell with a custom piece of DOM such as some Bootstraps dropdown HTML so the user can update that cell.

I can use .getDOMNode() in the click event handler and then manipulate the DOM manually and insert the code, however if render() on this component was called due to a new updated state from a websocket event it would be overridden. If this race condition occurs, I need to inform the user instead of the DOM simply being replaced. I've just seen componentWillUpdate() though this still feels like I'm not using React correctly.

Is there a better approach ? It feels dirty to be manipulating the DOM and incorrect to change the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating internal component state is there for exactly this case. This component should be in charge of determining whether it is active or not. If you update state on the component when the click handler is triggered with something like `active: true`, then you trigger a re-render. In your render function add the additional DOM elements if `active` is true. Then you have three different possibilities that should be accounted for:

- `onBlur`
- `onUpdate` which can
  be triggered in two ways. either way you'll likely want to set
  `active: false` on state.

  - websockets - you will need to inform your
    user here probably regardless of if the component is `active` or not
  - user - which will just update normally

Doing it this way means that React is always in full control of the DOM, which is a really good way to avoid issues with React.